# Decode json file using Smarty

Tags: json, youtube, smarty

I am trying to Decode json file from youtube. I'm not an expert with Smarty. I cant get my head round how to do this. This is my attempt and cant workout how to do this. I know I am reading the file as I did a {$feed}.  Can please someone tell me what I am doing worng and how to it. Thank you.

```
{capture assign=feed}{cache_remote_file url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=Duf5UUT......"}{/capture}

{foreach from=$feed|json_decode item=data}
       <p> title : {$data->items->snippet->title}  </p>
        <p> img : {$data->items->snippet->thumbnails->default->url}  </p>
 {/foreach}
```

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "9ZzDWJlUMjKGsGwGvtEREF_adhk",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "L3XeWemLM2vSCJh_RkWQgIjUbs4",
      "id": "Duf5UUT4ESg",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2021-07-21T16:39:22Z",
        "channelId": "UCEUfZ0aVKoC80RIAfvTBfDw",
        "title": "A.....Z",
        "description": "Shef......ling about this",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/D...g/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          ......................
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{capture assign=feed}{cache_remote_file url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=Duf5UUT......"}{/capture}

{assign var=itemArray value=$feed|json_decode:true}

{foreach from=$itemArray item=data}
<p> title : {$data->items->snippet->title} </p>
<p> img : {$data->items->snippet->thumbnails->default->url} </p>
{/foreach}
```

Would you please try above code I have added additional statement for the decoding the json

{assign var=itemArray value=$feed|json_decode:true}

This statement will decode the json and assign decoded json to $itemArray variable, then you use $itemArray in foreeach loop as shown in above code.

I have tried in my local and it works !!!

I hope it would help you.